# Invalid route action: [App\Http\Livewire\trips\Active]

Tags: laravel-livewire

The project is running well on local machine but when updating it on centos server, it gives the error Invalid route action: [App\Http\Livewire\trips\Active].  the rest of the routes are working fine apart from the ones on in the subfolders trips.

See the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG5vs.jpg)

Here is my web.php

```
Route::get('/active',\App\Http\Livewire\trips\Active::class)->name('active');
```

Here is the controller

class Active extends Component
{

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.trips.active');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be the `trip` part.

Try to change:
`Route::get('/active',\App\Http\Livewire\trips\Active::class)->name('active');`

To:
`Route::get('/active',\App\Http\Livewire\Trips\Active::class)->name('active');`

Base on image you've attached, you had `Trips` with Uppercase `T`.

Don't forget to also check, class namespace, I'm telling this, because you're using `PHPStorm`, and this `IDE` add imports base on namespace as far as i know.

In term of developing, when developing at local, you're basically might not see anything wrong (in most cases, Windows or Mac), but as you said, uploading to server with different `OS` might act in other ways (Specially linux OS), and case-sensitive is something that is always might considered.